# perl case convention with stringi

Tags: r, stringi

I can use the `perl` argument in `gsub` to change the case of individual subexpressions.  For example if I want to find a lower case `i` followed by and apostrophe or end of string (redundant here) I could do:

```
gsub("(\\bi(\\b|'))", "\\U\\1", "i am able to move do it as i'm going to.", perl = TRUE)

## [1] "I am able to move do it as I'm going to."
```

Notice `I` and `I'm` are caps but `it` is not.

How can I do the same thing (is it possible) using **stringi** given that base and **stringi** use different regex engines.

```
stri_replace_all_regex("i am able to move do it as i'm going to.", "(\\bi(\\b|'))", "\\U$1")

## [1] "1 am able to move do it as 1'm going to."
```

Comment: I don't think you can, at least not with a single function call. Is this just curiosity or is `gsub` not good/fast/... enough for you?

Comment: https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/131 does this help?

Comment: @eddi More a curiosity as I like to do everything in stringi for its uniform inputs.

Comment: @Chris I think so.  I believe that's the answer.